# How can I set the font colour?

Tags: c#, text, fonts, colors, overlay

I am Working with Visual C#. When overlay a text on the Picture, How can I set the font color?

```
graphicsImage.DrawString(textBox1.Text,
new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold)
SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(10, 210));
```

Comment: Can u plz add your xaml/aspx in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use SolidBrush like this,you will get red font:

```
graphicsImage.DrawString(textBox1.Text, new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(Color.Red), new Point(10, 210));
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no `Font` `Color` property, instead you should use the right **Brush**.
Do not forget *disposing* `IDisposable`, in your case:

```
  using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red)) { // <- Let your text be red
    using (Font font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold)) {
      // Paint the text with selected
      //  font - Arial 12 Bold
      // brush - solid red
      graphicsImage.Graphics.DrawString(
        textBox1.Text,       // <- what (text)
        font,                // <- font
        brush,               // <- color
        new Point(10, 210)); // <- where
    }
  }
```